# How to comment sh scripts in Make

Tags: bash, makefile, comments

Make's semantics force complex sh scripts to be broken up using `\`. Make turns those recipes into (arbitrarily long) one-liners. Therefore, I can't use `#` for comments. The Make function `$(info my comment goes here)` works, but the comment is printed even when the recipe itself isn't invoked.

I would like to have something like `rem "string"` in sh.

What I have been using so far is `$(call rem, my comment goes here)` in Make, 
which I define as:

```
rem = $(if,$(1))
```

But I'd like to not reinvent the wheel if something already exists and I just missed it. In particular, in sh I'd like something that preserves pipes, or at the very least stdout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the shell's do-nothing operator, which is `:`.  So like:

```
all:
        @echo "hi" ; : this is a comment ; echo "there"
```

Just be aware that the *shell* does expand these, so if you want to use special characters like quotes, backticks, etc. you should escape them from the shell if you're worried they'll cause problems.

*ETA*:

If you want something that won't interfere with shell behaviors like pipelines, you can't do that with any shell construct; all possible methods will cause syntax errors in the shell.

You'll have to use a make construct to force make to get rid of the text before it invokes the shell.  The example you have kind of works, but not for the reason you think.  If you really wanted to use a user-defined function `rem` then to run it you'd need to invoke `call`, as in:

```
$(call rem, my comment goes here)
```

What your method is doing is, since there is no function `rem` defined, it's looking up the variable named `rem my comment goes here` and that variable doesn't exist, so it expands to the empty string.  You can see this for yourself by having your `rem` function actually invoke `$(info ...)` or something: it will never be printed.

So you can continue to use the `$(rem ...)` syntax but you might as well remove the `rem = $(if,$(1))` since it's not used anyway, and will just confuse people.  Or you could use something smaller like `$(: my comment goes here)` or whatever.  Really you can put anything in there as long as it doesn't expand to a valid variable name.

I should point out that this is not necessarily future-proof; since variable names containing whitespace are not allowed anymore in make, it's possible that make will decide to handle a variable *reference* containing whitespace in a different way, sometime in the future.

Comment: That's excellent! Thank you. I though that : was just the null statement. Of course grepping : in man bash is completely useless.

Comment: That's great. Thanks for your time. I like the `$(: )`. It is shorter than `$(call rem, )`, and if you know about `:` in sh it looks reasonable. The only problem remaining is that of confusing people -- That is why I use `$(call rem, )` instead of just `($if, )` in the first place. The latter should always work, but it just looks like something was forgotten. Can you see anyway that `$( my comment goes here)`, i.e., a leading space, could ever mean something reasonable?

Comment: I don't see how it could but you never know.  My concern with that as it seems even more confusing (to me) than `:`; people reading it will say "why is there a leading space here?" and delete it, and it will still work...

Comment: You might want to delete your comments 1 and 2 above. I edited your response to incorporate my comments that I have deleted, but I don't have enough reputation to change your comments. Once you are done I'll also delete this comment. If you have any Qs let me know. Thanks!